# Traverse to the bottom of the folder tree linux

Tags: linux, bash

So I wanted to execute this command on every file where a certain string was.

This is the script I found:

```
replace $old_string $new_string -- path
```

And it worked. The problem is I had to do this:

```
replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" -- ./*/*
```

Then this:

```
replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" -- ./*/*/*
```

Then this:

```
replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" -- ./*/*/*/*
```

and so on. Finally, I got to the end, and it all worked.

But now I want to write a script for future usage, and obviously, I don't want to just create an endless loop, that tries to go deeper and deeper.

So how can I make the script traverse down the tree and change the files on the way?

My script right now:

```
echo "Give me the old string"
read old_string
echo "Give me the new string"
read new_string
echo "Give me the path"
read path

cd $path
replace $old_string $new_string -- #**/* something like this? I'm stuck here
```

> ~/Documents/Projects/uczichapp-react/src$ replace "import {firebase}" "import firebase" -- ./*/**
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/classes' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/globals' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/navigation' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/shared' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/solver' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)
>
> replace: Error reading file './Components/student' (Errcode: 21 - Is a directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -rl pattern` gives you the list of files under current dir matching pattern. Then you can use it to feed replace to do your modifications.

```
grep -rl "import firebase" | xargs replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" --
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the `find` command and piping its output to `xargs`:

```
find . -type f | xargs replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" --
```

or by using `find` to exec directly:

```
find . -type f -exec replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" -- {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash has the `globstar` option. Once enabled with `shopt -s globstar` you can write `**` to select all paths of arbitrary depth.

The combined globs  `*/*`, `*/*/*`, `*/*/*/*`, and so on list all files and directories starting one layer below the working directory.
The glob `*/**` is not exactly equivalent but should work for you. It will list all directories starting zero layers below the working directory and all files starting one layer below the working directory. Since `replace` cannot handle directories anyway that shouldn't be more of a problem than in `*/*`, `*/*/*`, and so on.

```
shopt -s globstar
replace "import firebase" "import {firebase}" -- ./*/**
```

Comment: I edited the question to add the error I'm getting along with the script

Comment: @AlexIronside Didn't you get similar errors with `*/*`, `*/*/*` and so on? These globs may also list directories.

Comment: Yes. But I needed the script to go through every folder until it reached the end. This one didn't go further in

Comment: @AlexIronside Maybe I misunderstood your scenario. Could you extend your question by a small example? Look at the output of `printf '.\n├── dirA\n│   ├── dirD\n│   │   └── fileG\n│   ├── dirE\n│   └── fileF\n├── dirB\n└── fileC\n'`; which paths do you want to select? Using `find` seems to be the better approach if you want to exclude directories, see Marcus' answer.